# Would someone please give me insight into the two bulges in our ceiling?

Tags: walls, ceiling, crack

[image]

[image: Bulge wall]

We’ve noticed these two bulges appear on our ceiling that run along the full length of the ceiling, looks like there is a slight hairline crack on it also.

We do air dry our clothes in this room so was wondering if it could possibly be due to the humidity?

My worry is though that there is a thin long crack that runs along the whole wall that meets the ceiling, I was hoping this wouldn’t all be linked with movement of the building itself

I’ve only noticed these two bulges recently, the cracks have been there since we moved in over a year ago

Comment: Can you give any history of how long they been there?  Off hand would say not a good drywall mudding job if they been like that for a long time.  If new/recent maybe a roof leak.

Comment: How far apart are they? If 4' then that would increase odds of a drywall issue.

Comment: I noticed hairline crack a while ago running down the side of the ceiling and wall where they meet. Thought I’d check it out again and noticed the ceiling but could have been like that for quite a while in all honesty. Searched online and panicked it’s a serious issue

Comment: Any major wind storms or earthquakes recently? With the damage spread around like that, I'm skeptical of a roof leak. Has the humidity been unnaturally high lately? Running a combustion heater indoors, for instance, will elevate the humidity.

Comment: No major storms or anything recently, there is hairline cracks around the walls and some areas of the ceiling but they have been like this a little while just never noticed these two areas before

Comment: Are you committed to fixing it? Seems like time to cut into a seam to look under the paint. Hopefully it is just bad workmanship. If that were the case, though, I would expect some instigating event like a windstorm or humidity spike. I'd climb into the attic and search for water sources before making a mess of the ceiling.

Comment: It helps if you edit the question to answer the comments.  It improves the question.

Comment: Simple response is paint is separating from the ceiling. The "Why" is going to require investigation.

Comment: We air dry the clothes in this room on a dryer, could the moisture and humidity from this cause such a thing?

Comment: Or is more than likely something from above? Appreciate the comments thank you

Comment: @Nelson that doesn't look like paint peeling to me.  Just looks like a poor mud job with insufficient feathering.

Comment: @user179516 please take all the info you've shared in comments and [edit] it into the question. As it stands your question is rather vague and needs more details. Burying the details down here in the comments means people don't see them and either ask again or just skip the question all together. Comments can also be deleted, loosing important info.

Comment: @freeman appreciate it I’ve updated it with a new photo too

Comment: Looks like the joint tape is pulling away from the sheetrock.